# Strange behaviour when two script files added to the workspace MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, file, workspace, solver

I'm using MATLAB R2017a. I've got two script files in the workspace. In the first one I solve a system of nonlinear equations and I set a condition on the variables that they must be positive. In the second files I do the same but without this condition. I run the first file and get the positive solution. When I run the second one afterwards, I get the positive solution as well even though I didn't create any conditions on the vars. If I put "clear all" then in the second file I get not only positive solution. What's going on? I didn't seem to have it in previous versions of MATLAB.

Here's the code of the first file:

```
function systrajs

c = 0.19;
mu1 = 2.1;
s1 = 0.01;
r2 = 0.94;
b = 0.03;
s2 = 0;

par = [c mu1 s1 r2 b s2];

eqpoints(par);

end

function eqpoints(par) 

c = par(1);
mu1 = par(2);
s1 = par(3);
r2 = par(4);
b = par(5);
s2 = par(6);

syms x y z positive

F = [c*y - mu1*x + x*z + s1; r2*y*(1 - b*y) - x*y; z - x*y + s2];

eq = solve(F, [x y z]);
eq = double([eq.x eq.y eq.z]');
disp('The solution:');
disp(eq);

end
```

Here's the code of the second script file:

```
function syssolve

syms x y z

c = 0.19;
mu1 = 2.1;
s1 = 0.01;
r2 = 0.94;
b = 0.03;
s2 = 0;

F = [c*y - mu1*x + x*z + s1; r2*y*(1 - b*y) - x*y; z - x*y];

eq = solve(F,[x y z]);
sol = double([eq.x eq.y eq.z]');
disp(sol);

end
```

So, as you can see, in the first file I marked the variables as positive. And it really gives only positive solutions. In the second one solution may be of any type. But if I run it right after the first file I still will be getting only positive solutions. If I close and open the second file (or just write "clear all") then I'm getting not only positive solutions. Why?

Comment: What are the names of the files you saved these to, and how are you specifically calling them in your code?

Comment: @gnovice they have the same names at the functions: systrajs.m and syssolve.m. They are placed in the same folder. I run each one by pressing "F5" or "Run" in matlab when the needed file is opened